# turn an array to be a json object using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How to turn array like below

```
arr = [{
"a":1,
"b":2,
"c":c
}]
```

into a json object?

```
arr = {
"a":1,
"b":2,
"c":c
}
```

Comment: What is `c` in `"c":c`? and why not just `arr = arr[0]`?

Comment: Well, you already have a plain object in the 0th index of an array and `JSON.stringify()` exists so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). **JSON.stringify** Converts a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string.

```
arr = [{
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "c":c
  }]
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: @Dean Jason this may help you :)